# Elasticsearch pods cant get volume

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, disk-volume

I used the official elasticsearch helm chart onto my GKE cluster. However, the pods cannot start with the error: `pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims`. I can see that the persistent volume claim has been created in the GCP console, but the status is Pending, since forever. I am not sure why is the volume claim stuck. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I figured this out. My cluster did not have a storage class ssd.